# rollapply outputing two or more columns

Tags: r, xts

I am trying to use rollapply so that I only use it once, rather than multiple times and then merging the results. The idea being that I want to get multiple bits of data from an `xts` object. In the below mock example I would like to be able to get the sum and the maximum value of the sliding window.

```
require(xts)
v <- xts(rnorm(100),Sys.Date()-100:1)
rollapply(v,width=10,function(y){c(sum(y),max(y))})
```

This leads to the following error...

```
Error in xts(xx, tt, if (by == 1) attr(data, "frequency")) : 
  NROW(x) must match length(order.by)
```

The below is the sessionInfo I was running:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-apple-darwin9.8.0/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9-3 zoo_1.7-9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.15.2     lattice_0.20-10
```

I thought I had this figured out, before but clearly not....

Comment: If you replace `v` with `as.zoo(v)` in `rollapply(v, ...)` then it works.

Comment: hmm, i get the error message: 
`Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("2013-01-24", "2013-01-25", "2013-01-26",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`
when trying: 
`rollapply(as.zoo(v),width=10,function(y){c(sum(y),max(y))})`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I get `Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("2013-01-24", "2013-01-25", "2013-01-26",  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent` R3.0.0 Win 64 ,  ‘1.7.9’ zoo and ‘0.9.3’ xts

Comment: Sorry. Try this: `z <- as.zoo(v); dim(z) <- NULL; r <- rollapply(z,width=10,function(y){c(sum(y),max(y))}); x <- as.xts(r)` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of the current implementation when the input only has one column.  You can work around it by ensuring the input has more than one column, setting `by.column=FALSE`, and adapting your function to only use one column.

For example:

```
require(xts)
v <- xts(rnorm(10),Sys.Date()-10:1)
f <- function(y) c(sum=sum(y[,1]), max=max(y[,1]))
rollapply(merge(v,v), width=3, f, by.column=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can always count on you Joshua!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this minor limitation going to be corrected anytime soon so that it can handle single column inputs?

Comment: @h.l.m: I added it to the feature request tracker, but I cannot tell you when I (or someone else) will actually patch it.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it...

```
sapply( c("sum" , "max" ) , function(x) rollapply( v , width = 10 , FUN = eval(x) , align = "left" ) )
#              sum       max
#  [1,] -2.43662744 1.6931489
#  [2,] -1.95346657 1.6931489
#  [3,] -0.66191032 1.6931489
#  [4,] -1.97506474 1.6931489
#  [5,] -3.12090491 1.6931489
#  [6,] -6.32315512 0.6908325
#  [7,] -3.09130768 2.4151086
#  [8,] -1.27864497 2.4151086
#  [9,] -0.20942059 2.4151086
# [10,] -0.39156830 2.4151086
```

Comment: I think that is still running `rollapply` twice using that method, and also in my real example, the functions are a lot more involved than just a simple `sum` and `max`, so don't quite think it would work...

Comment: It should do if you define the functions first and the only thing the function needs to *get* is values from the column. Why don't you try it. Yes it is running rollapply twice, once for each function you want to evaluate. If this isn't sufficient then give an example of the function you want to run and the data sufficient to run it.

Comment: Yeh i figured you could do that...but the bigger issue is the carrying out of `rollapply` twice...my datasets are quite large...also in your example output...you dont seem to have a date/time index...,where as `rollappply` does have one...I know its easily fixed...but just letting you know...

Comment: Ok, I don't know if you can apply two functions at once in `rollapply` (i'm sure you *must* be able to!), and to get the timestamps just add `index(v)` into the anonymous function in `sapply`. Cheers!

Comment: I thought that you "must" be able to too..and was hoping for a quick answer...but will have to wait and see and what the SO contributors have to offer....